# Selecting HTML content and replacing

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a little issue with jquery .

Let say i have the following statement :

```
var content = $('#details').html();
```

How do i find something inside **content** ?

This is what i've tried :

```
// i want to empty the data inside the id=student
content.find('#student').html('');
```

But since content is a string ... how can i assign HTML to a variable and be able to search that ?

**Update :**

Here is what i'm trying to achieve :

I have an ajax query and i need the (#details) structure intact .

If i empty the structure and then for a different ajax query i might need to do some replacement inside #student which wont be available because it was cleared ...

ex:

```
<div id="details">

 <div id="student">
   <span> {%weeks%} </span>
 </div>

 <div id="teacher">
   <span> {%whatever%} </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

so sometime i need to clear student / sometime teacher depending on the ajax query , that's why i make a copy of the html .

Comment: it's an id so it should be unique.. so why not just use the id `$('#student').html('')`

Comment: Remove the `html` from the first code and it will work.

Comment: `$('#details').find('#student').html('');`

Comment: I dont want to modify the real code , just the copy that i've made , i want to leave the structure intact .

Comment: @undefined if i modifiy the structure of #details and then i want to assign the content of #details to another variable will i have the original values ?

Comment: @undefined if i do the way you said ... and modifiy the structure it will be lost ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IDs must be *unique* you can select the element directly by ID which is more efficient that creating a redundant jQuery object.

```
$('#student').html('');
```

You can also use empty method:

```
$('#student').empty();
```

Note that if you are using ajax, you can use `html` method for changing the html content of the element and there is no need to removing html contents.

```
// ...
success: function(data) {
     $('#student').html(data);
}
```

In case that you want to cache the object, you can use `end` method for returning to previous state:

```
var $content = $('#details');
$content
   .find('#something').foo().end()
   .find('#anotherElement').bar().end()
```

Or if you want to copy the element, use `clone` method:

```
var $contentCloned = $('#details').clone();
```

Comment: i know i can change the content , what i need is 1 content and copies of it and be able to search that content and do replacement .

Answer (score 1):

you can use the selecter

```
$('#student', content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do

```
$('#details').find('#student').html('')
```

**OR better**

```
$('#student').html('')
```